# Rails 3 -NoMethodError (undefined method `original_filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, paperclip, uploadify

I'm using Rails 3, Uploadify, to send images to S3.

Right now all the images being upload have the MIME: application/octet-stream

I'd like to fix that but I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `original_filename' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x107c81998>):
  app/models/photo.rb:29:in `upload_file='
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:15:in `upload'
  app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:14:in `call'
```

I think this is because all the tutorials out there aren't Rails 3 friendly. Anyone have any ideas? Here's the code:

```
# Controller

def create
  @photo = Photo.new(:upload_file => params[:photo][:image])
  ...
end

# Model

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base  
  require 'mime/types'
  ...
  def upload_file=(data)
    data.content_type = MIME::Types.type_for(data.original_filename).to_s
    self.image = data
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Uploadify, but it seems to be just a javascript generator...

You're passing a params value in as 'data' for #upload_file= . Then you're calling a method (#original_filename) on params[:photo][:image]. Rails is saying that params[:photo][:image] doesn't have such a method.

Is there some kind of File class in 'mime/types'? Should you be creating that File object first?

```
file = File.new(params[:photo][:image])
```

and then change that files attribute:

```
file.content_type = ...
```

EDIT:

Are you using the paperclip gem? The tutorial that you are using is using paperclip. So in "@asset.file_content_type = MIME::Types.type_for(@asset.original_filename).to_s", I think @asset is an instance of paperclip's File class which does have a #original_filename method. However, I don't see a #file_content_type=() method in the paperclip docs.

Comment: thanks but I don't know... Im trying to following the tutorial here: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/07/21/uploadify-and-rails23/